# Formal notation for Git (repository, branch, commit) tuple

Tags: git, version-control

**Use case**: I am logging my CI pipeline that deploys the tip of a specific branch of a repository.

Although plain, verbose English is always an option, a standardized format for representing a specific commit from a specific branch of a repository seems more appropriate.

I would imagine that such a notation would be indispensable for logging/documentation purposes; something along the lines of:

TIMESTAMP: REPO`<separator1>`BRANCH`<separator2>`COMMIT -> HOST

If this can be generalized across version control systems, all the better.
My Google searches have not thrown up anything worthwhile on the subject.

Comment: In Git, a commit may be associated with zero, one, or more branches.

Comment: Afaik there is no "the convention". Are you referring to anything specific? Probably you should describe bigger piece of your problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I realize that. My use case eschews dangling commits.

Comment: @max630 use case updated.

Comment: @Slaiyer Where do you execute CI build for your git repo? For some CI build systems, they can read/record and repo, branch and commit automatically.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Jenkins + Git plugin, which populates individual environment variables, but afaik does not provide a prepared combination of these that I can simply curl to team chat, etc. To clarify, I already have the crucial components - just looking for stardardized/conventially used glue to put the together.

Comment: "standard" usually means that it is consumed by some software. Which kind of software do you think could consume such log? If such software exists, could it have specific format specified somewhere in its documentation?

Comment: for example, you can request from Teamcity [log of builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#RESTAPI-BuildRequests), whigh seem to contain the information which you asked, and more. Does it look like what you ask?

Comment: @max630 I cannot view any content on the link you provided. I plan to set up a metric analyzer that will chart the reliability of code from different commits over time, additionally grouped by branches - a feature that requires easily greppable logs. I believe the question now boils down to whether I should simply go ahead with my own custom format string for generating these logs in the absence of a commonly used "standard".

Comment: Apparently the mobile link does not work in desktop browsers, here is [the desktop link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such settings and configurations for git itself to show repo, branch, commit together.

As Jonathon mentioned, the relationship among repo, branch and commit usually does not as 1:1:1.

And if you want to get if a certain commit belongs to a remote repo or a branch, or which repo, branch(es) the certain commit belongs to, you can use use scripts to achieve it. Main commands used for the script as:

- Check a certain commit belongs to which branch(es):

  ```
  git branch --contains <commit>
  ```
- Check if a branch has tracking branch (in order to get the remote repo):

  ```
  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <branch>@{upstream}
  ```

Comment: Upvoted for good info, but I'm afraid I was looking for something else entirely. I have updated my use case in the question. Would be obliged if you could have another look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition

```
timestamp: repo/branch#commit -> HOST
```

e.g.

```
20200506_134321: my-site/master#c37107b0c -> HOST
```